# jquery animate: change span color not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

i have a span with class : cash_warn. I want to change the color of the span with a jquery animation, however it does not work.

What i have right now:

```
$('.cash_warn').animate({ color: "#ff8484" }, 500);
```

On the other side, this does work correctly, but it does not animate it:

```
$('.cash_warn').css('color',"#ff8484");
```

html:

```
<div class=" friends-shadow detailreward3 detailreward"  style="position:absolute;
 height:71px;  width:238px; left: 453px; top: 40px; padding:20px; z-index:99; font:
 bold 11px Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;">

<span style=" color:#fff" class="cash_warn">
text
</span>

<br /> <br />

 more text
</div>
```

Any idea what is going wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't animate color unless you use jQuery `color` plugin. ([GitHub](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-color))

> All animated properties should be animated to a single numeric value, except as noted below; most properties that are non-numeric cannot be animated using basic jQuery functionality (For example, width, height, or left can be animated but background-color cannot be, unless the jQuery.Color() plugin is used). Property values are treated as a number of pixels unless otherwise specified.

[**Source**](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)

> Note: The jQuery UI project extends the .animate() method by allowing some non-numeric styles such as colors to be animated. The project also includes mechanisms for specifying animations through CSS classes rather than individual attributes.

Comment: thanks, solved. Ill add it as an accepted answer when possible

Answer (score 0):

## CSS3 solution

Here are my 0.2$.
With CSS3 and a bit of jQuery?

### *[demo jsBin](http://jsbin.com/urutiq/edit#javascript,html,live)*

HTML:

```
<span class="cash_warn"> <!-- removed inline style-->
    text
</span>
```

CSS:

```
span.cash_warn{
    color: transparent;              /*set to transparent*/
    text-shadow: 0 0 0 #fff;         /*we concentrate the text shadow*/
    -webkit-transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
}
span.go_animate{                    /*this will be added by JS*/
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #f00;
}
```

And finally:

```
var textInt = setTimeout (function(){
  $('span.cash_warn').addClass('go_animate');
},1000); // after one second ... add the 'go_animate' class
```

---

## XBrowser solution

If you want a crossbrowser solution - than we can do a nice trick:
we can replicate that element using `.clone()`,
get it's positions,
fade out the original one and fade in the clone. :)

here you go:

### *[jsBin demo2](http://jsbin.com/urutiq/3/edit)*

```
$('.cash_warn').each(function(){
  
  var spanPos = $(this).position();
  $(this)
    .fadeTo(1500,0)              // fadeOut original
    .clone()                     // clone it
    .appendTo($(this).parent())  // append to parent element
    .addClass('spanClone')       // add a class if you need it for (CSS).
    .hide()                      // hide the clone
    .css({position:'absolute', left:spanPos.left, top: spanPos.top, color: 'red'}) // you don't need 'color' and 'position' if you have defined that already in the CSS for .spanClone
    .fadeTo(1500,1);             // after positions are set... fade it in!
  
});
```

Comment: I mentioned it's CSS3 :) no, this will not work. Depends on your needs, but if you want I can give you a crossbrowser solution with jQuery only (no css3)!

Comment: @DanStern Reedited my answer. now you  have 2 examples. hope they'll do the job. Cheers